# Selecionar varias categorias de filmes

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boas, deparo-me com o seguinte quebra-cabeças (para mim) que é o seguinte, eu sinceramente sei como começar a fazer o que eu quero que é varios `checkbox's` cada um com o seu `value`. Depois daí é que nao sei mesmo como fazer..

> ATENÇÃO, nao estou a dizer para me fazerem tudo, apenas dar umas dicas.

Como poderei fazer para colocar tudo na mesma coluna na `base de dados` e depois por exemplo, apresentar da seguinte maneira na minha pagina:

> Exemplo:

Categoria: `Categoria1, Categoria2, Categoria3, Etc..`

Comment: Não faça isso! não grave vários valores em uma coluna você terá alguns problemas já pensou em como fazer consultas por um valor especifico ou atualizar? grave isso em uma nova tabela(associativa).

Comment: Pode ajudar-me a fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, uma alternativa é adicionar os valores selecionados em um array e no PHP através do `foreach`realizar as inserções em seu banco.

```
foreach ($categorias as $categoria) { // $categoria assume um valor do array 
        // sua inserção no banco usando $categoria
}
```

E para consultar basta realizar um select das categorias.

Comment: Como assim? E como ficaria a base de dados? :ss